# Creating walla from dialogue

Tags: audio, noise, walla

I have some dialogue that is clean and it's easy to understand what the people are saying but I was wondering if there is a way to create this dialogue into walla so it's unrecognizable.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you just want to record a crowd.  That way all the voices blend in an ambience.  However, with a combination of EQ (bright frequencies are important for intelligibility, cut those), ambience/reverb (very important to make the different pieces blend together), layering several pieces of dialogue over each other, and possibly using other plugins that can double, pitch-shift, formant shift, or whatnot to make an individual piece of dialogue sound like multiple people...make sure to pan your different layers a bit too so they sound like multiple sources.

Overall, definitely more time-consuming than recording the sound you need or using a library sound.  And the result will likely be worse.  If you're doing this as an exercise, have fun with it for sure.

Comment: Thanks! I am just experimenting but I wasn't sure how to start. It's for an apartment building hallway so I want the voices to sound like they are coming different apartments while inside of the hallway.

Comment: Ah interesting...sound heard through walls definitely has a lot of ambient reflection and usually a LPF.

Comment: How much walla would there be inside of the apartment itself? Would I have to lower the high/mids even more than the hallway walla?

Comment: Depends on what the walls are like I guess...the quality of the reflections are going to be different in the room than in the corridor, also you will be hearing more of people walking around, etc, in the apartment above through the floor, which just registers as thumps.  In the corridor you hear things through doors so ya, the dialogue might be slightly more intelligible there.